# Crankset for SRAM Apex Groupset

Tags: parts, crankset, sram, compatibility

I have SRAM Apex Shifters, FD, RD, and Brakes.

Can I use a SRAM Force BB30 Crankset?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Yes, generally SRAM's 10 speed road parts are cross compatible between apex, rival, force, and red. Do you have a BB30 frame though?

Comment: Very good question... I bought my bike on CL and don't know which model it is.  It definitely was changed... bc it has a combo of different components.  Tiagra shifters with Sora FD and RD.  I checked the archives and they didn't make a model like that.  To make things more complicated.  The crank is a 53/39.
http://www.bianchiusa.com/archives/09-bicycles/09-c2c/via-nirone-7-alu/09-c2c-nirone-alu-sora-trpl/
This looks like the bike... but the specs say it's a triple crankset... so maybe the previous owner changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use a SRAM Force BB30 Crankset?

Unfortunately, you will not be able to use the BB30 on your bicycle. You will need to search for a Sram Force GXP Crankset. You will also need to verify if your particular Bianchi is Italian threaded or not as not all Bianchi are.